# jquery toggle making links work eratically

Tags: jquery, navigation, toggle, anchor

I am working on making a navigation toggle down on click but when i test on my mobile device it opens up the link instead of just showing the nested list. I have tried a bunch of different things and searched this site extensively, but i can't figure it out.

http://www.duddywebdesign.com/doti  <- this is the test site, here is the markup

```
<nav>
    <a href="#" id="menu-button" id="showmenu">&#9776; Menu</a>
    <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Microdermabrasion</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">LED</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Massage</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Acupuncture</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Energy Work</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Packages</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

And here is the jquery:

```
$('#menu-button').click(function() {
    $('.menu').slideToggle('fast');
    return false;
});
$( "li" ).has( "ul" ).addClass( "cursor" );     
$('nav ul li a').click(function(e) {
    if ($(this).hasClass("cursor")) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }   
    $(this).next("ul").slideToggle("fast");
});
```

This is the newest code i've been trying to tweak, before that none of the links in the nav would work at all. Please help, thanks.

Comment: To clarify, on the mobile i want them to click "Services" and have it expand the list, but it will bring up the page for services.

Comment: Works fine here - http://jsfiddle.net/K3uEc/. I don't see how it can navigate to another page as there is no url in the link?

Comment: I am implementing this into a wordpress theme i am working on. The link does have a url in it in that example i linked at top

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('#menu-button').click(function(e) {
        $('.menu').slideToggle('fast');
        return false;
    });

    $( "li" ).has( "ul" ).addClass( "cursor" );

    $('nav ul li a').click(function(e) {
        if ($(this).hasClass("cursor")) {
             $(this).next("ul").slideToggle("fast");

    }
      e.preventDefault();

    });
```

Comment: I only want the link that has a sub-menu to not work when clicked, when i try this it makes all of the links not clickable, also this makes the sub-menu not toggle when clicked.